# InfluxQL Continuous Query which deletes data

Tags: influxdb

Is there a way to have a [continuous query](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/continuous_queries/) which deletes data, something like:

```sql
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "some_name" ON "mydb"
BEGIN
  delete from "some_measurement" where something='bad'
END
```

When this is run with InfluxQL 1.8, there is an error

> ERR: error parsing query: found DELETE, expected SELECT at line 1, char 53

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, however you're not necessarily out of luck as this is exactly the sort of workflow that [retention policies](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/manage-database/#create-retention-policies-with-create-retention-policy) were designed to handle in concert with continuous queries.

Assuming your use case is something like "downsample this data into a different measurement, then delete the high granularity data", the [official documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/guides/downsample_and_retain/) provides an excellent overview.